# Why the `cycle()` method exists if `ChunksMut` is never `Clone?`

Tags: rust

The https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.ChunksMut.html has the cycle method: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Cycle.html#method.cycle that works only when `Self: Clone`

However, `ChunksMut` does not implement `Clone`, therefore I cannot do this:

```
fn main() {
    let a = &[1,2,3,4,5,6];
    let mut chunks = a.chunks_mut(2);
    let cycle = chunks.cycle();
    for c in cycle {
        
    }
}
```

Why the `cycle()` method exists if `ChunksMut` is never `Clone?`

Comment: `ChunksMut::cycle()` exists because `ChunksMut` gets it from `Iterator`. And `ChunksMut` cannot be `Clone` because if it were, you could write `let chunks2 = chunks.clone()` and use `chunks.next()` and `chunks2.next()` to get two mutable references to the same piece of data.

Comment: This function hasn't been created specifically for ChunksMut. It exists for those other iterators which happen to implement Clone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ChunksMut` [implements the `Iterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.ChunksMut.html#trait-implementations).

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for ChunksMut<'a, T>
```

And the [`cycle()` comes from](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cycle) the default implementation of `Iterator` trait. `cycle` has a predicate(`where Self: Clone`) which restrict calling `cycle` on types that are [not cloneable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html).

```
fn cycle(self) -> Cycle<Self>
where
    Self: Clone,
```

Comment: It's poses an interested question: should rustdoc hide functions inherited from a trait where the predicate is never satisified? I'm not sure it is possible with the current rustdoc infrastructure, though.